# Android ListView with Custom Adapter Has Visual Glitch

Tags: android, listview, optimization, android-listview, android-cardview

I'm new to Android programming and trying to figure out how to optimize my ListView adapter. I wrote a custom adapter to add CardViews to my ListView:

```
public class CardAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final ArrayList<CardView> cards = new ArrayList<CardView>();
    private Context context;

    public CardAdapter( Context context ) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void add( CardView view ) {
        cards.add( view );
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        if( i >= cards.size() || i < 0 )
            return null;
        return cards.get( i );
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return cards.get(i).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if( view == null ) {
            view = (CardView) getItem( position );
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

The MainActivity is something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView list = findViewById(R.id.notesList);
        CardAdapter adapter = new CardAdapter(getBaseContext());
        adapter.add( makeCard() );
        // repeat making cards however many times...
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private CardView makeCard() {
        CardView card = new CardView(this);
        // Do some things to customize the CardView
        return card;
    }


}
```

Now it seems like Android is trying to recycle the views, but is doing a lousy job of it. Initially the page looks fine, but as soon as I begin scrolling, the cards start to move all over the screen, the spacing changes, the cards begin to overlap, etc. [image: This is what the ListView looks like before scrolling] [image: and this is what it looks like after scrolling].

Note that I only scrolled for a couple seconds, this was not a gradual change, the cards were kind of 'jumping' around the screen. The only solution I have come up with so far is changing my `getView` to be:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return (CardView) getItem(position);
    }
```

And this works, but even loading ~10 items is very slow, and the scrolling lags.

Comment: Please post adapter xml file.

Comment: @Chintan I'm not sure what you're asking, do you mean activity_main.xml?

Comment: Your activity_main.xml and your card xml may help finding the problem, but I would first give a try to RecyclerView.

Comment: @RicardoA. Yeah, I'll take a stab at recyclerview later. The cards are created through code, there is no corresponding XML, could that cause any issues? Activity_main is just a linearlayout containing a listview.

Comment: Nah, those codes are probably ok, the problem should be your adapter or simply the implementation of ListView itself. As ghazanfar ali tried to explain, RecyclerView was created specifically to solve this kind of situation. And ListView is obsolete, so you should really change to RecylerView, even if it doesn't solve the problem, it's easier to find help when working with up-to-date technology, because most people are working with it.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use RecyclerView it uses view holder pattern that resolve all these lagging issues

Answer (score 0):

**Change your implementation from ListView to RecyclerView.**

> RecyclerView is a ViewGroup added to the android studio as a successor
>   of the GridView and ListView. It is an improvement on both of them and
>   can be found in the latest v-7 support packages. It has been created
>   to make possible construction of any lists with XML layouts as an item
>   which can be customized vastly while improving on the efficiency of
>   ListViews and GridViews. This improvement is achieved by recycling the
>   views which are out of the visibility of the user. For example, if a
>   user scrolled down to a position where the items 4 and 5 are visible;
>   items 1, 2 and 3 would be cleared from the memory to reduce memory
>   consumption.

From [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-recyclerview/). 
**Ps:** the link has a lot of explanation, tutorial and codes...

The RecyclerView was created specifically to solve the kind of problem you're having. It has a lot of improvements over ListView, like less memory consumption, less lagging, better scrooling...

Answer (score -1):

ok,its too simple

first remember u must pass what u want use in adapter,but now u just pass a (this) to this adapter.
use code below for your Constructor .

have good codding.

```
private final ArrayList<CardView> cards = new ArrayList<CardView>();
private Context context;

public CardAdapter( Context context , ArrayList<CardView> cards) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cards =cards
}
```

Comment: He's adding the cards later, there's absolutely no problem starting the adapter with an empty list.